# Saving the last thing done as an object?

Tags: r

I have a vector `x <- rnorm(100)` and whilst exploring my data I do:

```
x
```

Now I want to look at the `mean` of x, for which I could do:

```
mean(x)
```

But lets say instead I want to have a function `last()` which pulls in the last thing done in Rs history and saves it as an object, which would enable me to do:

```
mean(last())
```

I'd like to write a `last()` function if it doesn't already exist. But I cannot find a way to access (without saving and then reading back in) the history in any useful way via `history()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this working using `.Last.value`:

```
lv <- function() .Last.value
x = runif(100)
mean(lv())
```

I would be ok with using this in interactive mode, but using this in normal mode would make the code hard to read imo. So use at your own discretion.

Comment: And to save even more keystrokes, try `makeActiveBinding(".", function() .Last.value, env=.GlobalEnv) `   Then `mean(.)`